# Request to merge tag [fabric-twitter] with [twitter-fabric]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Given that the tag [fabric-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-twitter) is a synonym of [twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) and that[twitter-fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-fabric) has become the default tag (given the synonym) for all things related to Fabric, owned by Twitter, I'm requesting a merge of the two tags into one.

[image: tag synonyms screenshot]